# How to put a JAR file in a Play 2 project and use it?

Tags: dependency-management, playframework-2.0

In [Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework) 1, we can put some [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) files into the `/lib` directory. But there is no such a directory, and I don't find any information to do this.

Play 2 uses repositories, but sometimes I just want a quick and dirty way to use a JAR file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Play 2 applications are built using [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), you can just follow their convention for [unmanaged dependencies](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies): put your [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file in the `lib/` directory.