# Jars in lib folder not picked up when deploying play application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, dependency-management

I have built an application based on play framework 2.0.3. I have placed some jars in lib folder (unmanaged dependencies) which are used in my application like suggested in [How to put a JAR file in a Play 2 project and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287880/how-to-put-a-jar-in-a-play2-project-and-use-it)

All is fine when I run it from my local machine with `play run`

But when this application is deployed to Heroku, these jars are not picked up. I get compilation errors where these jars are used.

I even tried adding dependencies.yml with below content

```
require:
    - play 2.0.3
    - provided -> myjar 1.0

repositories:
  - provided:
      type:       local
      artifact:   "${application.path}/lib/[module]-[revision].jar"
      contains:
        - provided -> *
```

But still it didn't work.

My Start script (Procfile) is :

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

Can somebody throw some light on this problem ?

Comment: The dependencies.yml file is not used with Play 2.x versions. Anf did you add your jars in the lib/ folder to git ?

Comment: Yeah. It was my mistake. I had lib folder added into .gitignore file. It prevented the jars from being pushed to heroku. Got it working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since heroku uses git, make sure that you `lib` folder and all contained jars are properly managed by git, ie that they are not in your `.gitignore` file.